# Is it possible to use all mule features with anypoint studio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am new to mule technology and using anypoint studio.

May I know how to implement mule security manager in anypoint studio. Do we get any component in mule palette for this purpose.

And also how to implement retry policies using anypoint studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options for security manager. One of them is using Spring security. You can not find these component in the palette. You need to put this in xml only.

The retry policy you mean re-connection strategy?